# restoreState and saveState not working in Qt 4.8.2

Tags: c++, qt, savestate

the code is this:

file -> Conf.cpp

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QMainWindow>


Conf::Conf(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Conf)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //QCoreApplication :: setOrganizationDomain ("OrgDomain");
    //QCoreApplication :: setOrganizationName ("OrgName");
    //QCoreApplication :: setApplicationName ("AppName");
    //QCoreApplication :: setApplicationVersion ("1.0.0");


    QSettings settings;
    restoreGeometry(settings.value("mainWindowGeometry").toByteArray());
    restoreState(settings.value("mainWindowState").toByteArray());

}


Conf::~Conf()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Conf::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    ......

    QSettings settings;
    settings.setValue("mainWindowGeometry", saveGeometry());
    settings.setValue("mainWindowState", saveState());

    close();

}
```

file -> Conf.h

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Conf;
}

class Conf : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit Conf(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Conf();

private slots:

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Conf *ui;
};
```

Errors:

'restoreStates' was not declared in this scope

'saveStates' was not declared in this scope

I think that problem is of library, because the "restoreGeometry" and "saveGeometry" works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class inherit to QWidget but QWidget doesn't have any restoreState and saveState. It's in QMainWindow.

Comment: Thank you very much, but what parts of the code would have to change? or is it better to add another class?

Comment: something if it helps, I'm using linux.

Comment: Instead to save and restore in your conf you could add this in your mainWindow or send a pointer to your Conf constructor, save it then use it.